# Why does git fail on push/fetch with "Too many open files"

Tags: linux, git, config

I'm encountering an issue with Git where I'm receiving the following message:

```
> git fetch
error: cannot create pipe for ssh: Too many open files
fatal: unable to fork
```

The System Administrators have increased my file limit, but it has not corrected the issue. Additionally, I don't have an issue with creating new files with vi.

When trying to push a new branch, I get a similar message:

> git push origin test_this_broken_git
>   error: cannot create pipe: Too many open files
>   fatal: send-pack: unable to fork off sideband demultiplexer

Could somebody answer exactly why this is happening? I have not made any recent changes to my git config and have verified that manually.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two similar error messages:

```
EMFILE: Too many open files
ENFILE: Too many open files in system
```

It looks like you're getting `EMFILE`, which means that the number of files for an individual process is being exceeded.  So, checking whether `vi` can open files is irrelevant—`vi` will use its own, separate file table.  Check your limits with:

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
```

So on my system, there is a limit of 1024 open files in a single process.  You shouldn't need to ask your system administrator (please don't use the acronym SA, it's too opaque; if you must abbreviate, use "sysadmin") to raise the limit.

You may wish to check which files Git opens by running Git under `strace`.

This could be a bug in Git or in a library, or it could be you're using an old version of something, or it could be something more bizarre.  Try `strace` first to see which files it opens, and check whether Git closes those files.

**Update from Hazok:**

After using the above recommendations, it turns out the error was caused by too many loose objects.  There were too many loose objects because `git gc` wasn't being run often enough.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and tips. I didn't make the request to the SAs, they're trying to figure out the root cause still and it's been too long so I wanted to see what the gurus on Stackoverflow suggest :D

I tried strace and it's dumping a ton of stat, lstat, open, read, read, close commands on what appears to be each tag from where I broke out of the command.

Comment: Would you mind if I edited your answer to provide the final cause and resolution in it as well? I'd like to give you full credit for this one since it was a Git issue and running strace helped a ton.

Answer (score 6):

#### Why did this happen?

From [the git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#Documentation/git-gc.txt-gcauto):

> When there are approximately more than this many loose objects in the repository, git gc --auto will pack them. Some Porcelain commands use this command to perform a light-weight garbage collection from time to time. **The default value is 6700.**

Here "Some Porcelain commands" includes `git push`, `git fetch` etc. So if the max open files limit `ulimit -n` < 6700, you'll be eventually blocked by `git gc --auto` once you got ~6700 loose objects in a single git repo.

#### I'm in a hurry. How to fix it?

If you have sufficient permissions to adjust the system ulimit:

```
$ sudo ulimit -n 8192
```

Otherwise, you may disable `git gc` by setting `git config gc.auto 0`, so that you could push your local commits to the remote, delete the repo, and clone it back without thousands of loose objects.

#### How can we prevent this from happening again?

Set `git config --global gc.auto 200`, where 200 is some value less than your max open files limit. If you picked a too small value, `git gc` would run too frequently, so choose wisely.

If you set `gc.auto=0`, the loose objects will never be packed unless you run `git gc` manually. So there could be hundreds of thousands of files accumulated in the same directory, which might be a problem, especially for mechanical hard drive or Windows users. (See also: [How many files in a directory is too many?](https://serverfault.com/questions/98235) and  [Is it OK (performance-wise) to have hundreds or thousands of files in the same Linux directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735875)).