# git: Too many open files

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am trying to run `git gc` but I keep getting errors of too many open files.

```
warning: unable to access '.gitattributes': Too many open files
error: unable to open object pack directory: .git/objects/pack: Too many open files
fatal: failed to read object <hash>: Too many open files
error: failed to run repack
```

I don't know how to find what files are open and or how to close them.

I am using git version 2.13.0.windows.1 and Visual Studio code.

Comment: Try reboot. `lsof` can find all open handlers in linux but it doesn't work in windows.

Comment: Tried a reboot but no dice.

Comment: google for 'windows too many open files'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have have solved the problem with a work around. Removed the repo and cloned a remote. Thankfully everything seems fine. Should I still leave the question up in-case someone has a real answer?

Comment: @Len I've just posted an answer about about this topic at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66315779/5072722. You may lower the `gc.auto` threshold in `.gitconfig` to prevent this problem from happening again.